# Full automation pass as a part of dev pull request confirmation

Tags: javascript, git, tfs, protractor, pull-request

In order to improve my project's workflow (including Dev team + Automation team) we want to ensure that a dev PR doesn't harm other system processes and flows.
The idea is to automatically run automated test that are connected to the PR's files topic / title / path, according to some logic.
Here's my question - Is there any recommended way to logically connect automated tests related somehow to files that has been edited within the dev's PR?
Something like git manipulation, dedicated npm, etc?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: my opinion? there is no recommended ways for anything in IT. some practices work better in one company, the other are best in another company

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov do you have any ideas?

Comment: I do, but I could have written a book to answer your question... where exactly is your problem? in nutshell make a sort of pipeline, that would triger tests, make tests accept test suite name as a parameter. Read the changes of the commit and depending on path of changed files start tests with the test suite related to the changes. I know what i said won't help since the answer is too broad, and that is because the question is broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) in branch policy. There are a few critical branches in your repo that the team relies on always being in good shape, such as your `master` branch. [Require pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) to make any changes on these branches.

If a build validation policy is enabled, a new build is queued when either a new pull request is created, or if changes are pushed to an existing pull request targeting the branch. The build policy then evaluates the results of the build to determine whether the pull request can be completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both Sergey and Cece's responses and have a bulid trigger on PR but have the first task extract the list of files in the Commits of the PR and then start tests based on the changed files.

I would use PowerShell and the Rest API to get the PR info (list of files) and they go from there.